# RoR globalize2 - default translation after manual sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize2

I use globalize2, everything is ok, if I add new record to datanase using console it automatically adds default translation to _translations table.

But if I add some records using pure sql (phpmyadmin or so, without rails) than the record  to _translations table is not added. Is there any way how to invoke the translation?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is completely against rails conventions ! More-ever , globalize2  translation works under rails , using rails ORM . If you are directly making changes to database using phpmyadmin then its not possible to invoke the translations.